# Calculate total donations based on an attribute table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, aggregate-functions

I am trying to get a list of donors who have cumulatively donated $5K+ between two different campaigns. My data is something like this

Attributes table

| transactionid | attributevalue |
| --- | --- |
| 123231 | campaign 1 |
| 123456 | campaing 2 |
| 123217 | campaign 1 |
| 45623 | campaing 2 |
| 65791 | campaing 3 |
| 78931 | campaign 4 |
| 11111 | campaign 5 |
| 22222 | campaing 6 |

Donations table

| transactionid | donationamount | donorid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123231 | 2000 | 1233 |
| 123456 | 30000 | 1456 |
| 45623 | 8000 | 1233 |
| 78931 | 90 | 8521 |
| 11111 | 20 | 1233 |
| 22222 | 68 | 1456 |

Donor table

| donorid | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1233 | John |
| 1456 | Mary |
| 8521 | Karl |

This is what I tried, but the total I am getting is not right at all.

```
WITH test AS (
    SELECT don.donorid,don.donationamount,a.attributevalue
    FROM attributes table a 
    INNER JOIN donations don ON don.transactionid=a.transactionid
) 
SELECT d.donorid,
       SUM(CASE WHEN test.attributevalue='campaign 1' OR test.attributevalue='campaign 2' 
       THEN test.donationamount END) AS campaing_donation,
       SUM(test.donationamount) AS total_donations
FROM donortable d
INNER JOIN test ON d.donorid = test.donorid
GROUP BY d.donorid
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN test.attributevalue = 'campaign 1' OR test.attributevalue = 'campaign 2' THEN test.donationamount END) > 5000
```

but this is not working. My total donations sum is giving a value that is several times higher than the actual value.

Ideally, the final result would be something like this:

| donorid | campaign_amount | totalamount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1233 | 10000 | 10020 |
| 1456 | 30000 | 30068 |
|  |  |  |

Comment: Please show your desired results. And if you provide your sample data as DDL+DML you make it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: In your DDL include the primary, natural, and foreign keys so we don't need to guess at the relationships between the tables. Can a donor split a donation between campaigns? As crazy as it may sound, can multiple donors combine amounts into a single donation? And your query, as posted, refers to more than the 3 table "samples" you provided.

Comment: Struggling to understand your expected results. You want amount for 2 campaigns, DonorId has exactly 2 campaigns so why is the Campaign amount not also 30068 since 30000 is the value of only a single campaign?

Comment: @Stu for donorId 1456, this person donated $68 to campaign 6 and $30,000 to campaign 2. I am looking for donors who have total cumulative donations of $5K to either campaign 1 or 2, and to output the total donated to those campaigns(1 and 2) and also their total donated to all campaigns. So for 1456, this person has $30K to campaign 2 and $68 to Campaign 6 so their total is $30,068. I am having issues with the output. the sum totals are way too high for each row.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select
  sum (Donations.donationamount),
  donor.donorid,
  donor.name
from
    Attributes
join Donations on 
    Donations.transactionid = attributes.transactionid
Join Donor on
    donor.donorid = donations.donorid
Where
    Attribute.attributevalue in ('campaign 1','campaign 2')
Group by
    donor.donorid,
    donor.name
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged, you should add some explanatory comment

Comment: Sorry - I'm new I'll do better from now on

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #transection_tbl(tran_id int,attributevalue varchar(20))
create table #donation_tbl(tran_id int,donation_amount int ,donar_id int)


select donar_id,max(donation_amount) as 'campaing_amount',
sum(donation_amount) as 'totalamount'
from #transection_tbl as t1
inner join #donation_tbl as t2 on t1.tran_id=t2.tran_id
group by donar_id
having COUNT(attributevalue)=2
```